# how to make site header clickable and link back to homepage

Tags: php, html, wordpress, header, href

I am trying to make the site title of my header clickable and link back to the home page.  (For example, google.com - if you click the google logo you go back to the google homepage.)  I have added all of the correct code to my header.php but it still won't allow me to click the site title.  Does anyone see any errors or have any solutions? Thanks in advance.

my header.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * 
 *
 * 
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="ht-page">
<header id="ht-masthead" class="ht-site-header">
<div class="ht-container ht-clearfix">
<div id="ht-site-branding">
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'has_custom_logo' ) && has_custom_logo() ) :
the_custom_logo();
else : 
if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
<h1 class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
<?php else : ?>
<p class="ht-site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="ht-site-description"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- .site-branding -->

<nav id="ht-site-navigation" class="ht-main-navigation">
<div class="toggle-bar"><span></span></div>
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array( 
'theme_location' => 'primary', 
'container_class' => 'ht-menu ht-clearfix' ,
'menu_class' => 'ht-clearfix',
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
) ); 
?>
</nav><!-- #ht-site-navigation -->
</div>
</header><!-- #ht-masthead -->

<div id="ht-content" class="ht-site-content ht-clearfix">
```

my css

```html
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Header
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-masthead{
  background: #FFF;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ht-site-title{
font-family: 'futura_tbold';
    font-size: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 6px;
        line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left: 75px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;

    padding: 15px 0;
transition: padding 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
}

.ht-site-title a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}
.ht-site-description{
 color: #EEE;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-style: italic;
 line-height: 1;
}

.ht-site-description a{
 color: #333;
}











/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## General
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#ht-content {
    padding-top: 200px;
}
.ht-section {
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: #FFF;
}

.ht-section-title-tagline {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ht-section-title {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto 15px;
}

.ht-section-title:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-section-tagline {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#ht-page {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ht-site-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.3s ease;
  float: right;
}

.ht-sticky #ht-site-navigation {
  padding: 17px 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation .ht-menu {}

.ht-main-navigation ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.ht-main-navigation li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.ht-main-navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  min-width: 200px;
 right:0;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: -21px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    height:300px;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -moz-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 8px;
  border-top: 0;
}

.ht-sticky .ht-main-navigation ul ul ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #444;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
 text-align: left;
}
.ht-main-navigation ul ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.ht-main-navigation ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ht-main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.ht-main-navigation li:hover > a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation li:hover > a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation li:hover > a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.ht-main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.ht-main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a,
.page-template-home-template .ht-main-navigation .current > a,
.home.blog .ht-main-navigation .current > a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.site-main .comment-navigation,
.site-main .posts-navigation,
.site-main .post-navigation {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous,
.posts-navigation .nav-previous,
.post-navigation .nav-previous {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next,
.posts-navigation .nav-next,
.post-navigation .nav-next {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: what are you using for site title ? plain text or custom logo. I see the custom logo `the_custom_logo()` is not linking to home_url

Comment: Just plain text - my wordpress site name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean clicking the title of the tab or making the header tag clickable.

If you mean making the header tag clickable, then try the following snippet:

```css
header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header onclick="alert('Clicked')"></header>
```

If you want to make the title of tab clickable, you're out of luck.

It's impossible.

Comment: Live example at: [http://jsfiddle.net/4qx7r95s/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/4qx7r95s/1/)

Comment: I just want the site title to be clickable and to link back to the homepage.  For example google.com if you click on the google logo it will bring you back to the google home page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a text link, use a href, if you want an image link, put img tag in a tag

```css
* {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Google!</a>

<a href="https://google.com">
  <img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">
</a>
```

*Note:* Links wont work in here because of the snippet thingy